# Not able to access vagrant box from host on windows 10

Tags: windows, centos, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a vagrant box setup with below config

```
  config.vm.hostname = "devops-sk-vm"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.vm.box = "generic/centos8"
```

I have a Jenkins running on VM however I am not able to access that from host machine. below are the ports forward and I didn't supply any specific IP. Running Jenkins on 9003.

```
  for i in 9000..9100
      config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: i, host: i
  end
```

Box provider: Virtual box
version: 6.1.16
Vagrant version: 2.2.14
Host: Windows 10 Pro 2020
All inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this by checking the firewall service running on generic/centos8. firewalld service runs by default it seems and I had to whitelist the ports to get the traffic in.

Followed this guide to initially disable it and then open the ports.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7